# using savon with exacttarget's web service

Tags: ruby, soap, wsdl, savon, exacttarget

i am having problems forming my soap document for the following. this is also my first time using soap. after some research and recommendations, savon seems the way to go.

```
require 'savon'

client = Savon::Client.new("https://webservice.exacttarget.com/etframework.wsdl")

client.wsdl_soap_actions
# [:create, :retrieve, :update, :delete, :query, :describe, :execute, :perform, :configure, :schedule, :version_info, :extract, :get_system_status]

response = client.retrieve do |soap|
  soap.input = "Retrieve"
  soap.action = "Retrieve"
end
```

I got the following error on a security header that is missing.

```
Savon::SOAPFault: (q0:Security) Security requirements are not satisfied because the security header is not present in the incoming message.
 from /home/kj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/savon-0.7.9/lib/savon/response.rb:141:in `handle_soap_fault'
 from /home/kj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/savon-0.7.9/lib/savon/response.rb:81:in `initialize'
 from /home/kj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/savon-0.7.9/lib/savon/client.rb:95:in `new'
 from /home/kj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/savon-0.7.9/lib/savon/client.rb:95:in `method_missing'
 from (irb):8
 from /home/kj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/irb:17:in `<main>'
```

I've pasted the full response here. http://pastie.org/1349438

Could any kind soul help me out with this?

Answer (score 2):

ExactTarget's SOAP implementation is pretty weak.  You won't be able to use Savon's soap_actions at all.  You'll need to handcode most of the envelope as a hash and manually set the SOAPAction in the header.  Savon does take most of the guesswork out of the envelope header though.  Here's an example for pulling a list of filter subscribers:

```
client = Savon::Client.new do | wsdl, http, wsse |
  wsdl.document = 'https://webservice.s4.exacttarget.com/etframework.wsdl'
  wsse.credentials "username", "password"
end

res = client.request :ins0, 'RetrieveRequestMsg' do
  soap.body = {
    'RetrieveRequest' => 
    {
      'ObjectType' => 'Subscriber', 
      'Properties' => ['ID', 'SubscriberKey'],
      :attributes! => 
      {
        'ins0:Filter' => {"xsi:type" => "ins0:SimpleFilterPart"}
      },
      'Filter'     => 
      {
        'Property'   => 'SubscriberKey', 
        'SimpleOperator' => 'like', 
        'Value'          => 'string_to_filter_by'
      }
    }
  }
  http.headers['SOAPAction'] = 'Retrieve'
end
```

You also may need to remove the "s4" from the wsdl url depending on your account type.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this gem:

https://github.com/daws/exact_target_sdk

Ran across it a few days ago and it's made life much easier.

Answer (score 1):

You probably just need to send in your API credentials:

```
Savon::WSSE.username = "USERNAME_HERE"
Savon::WSSE.password = "PASSWORD_HERE"
```

before making requests.

Answer (score 0):

Is should be `client.wsdl.soap_actions`

Answer (score 0):

I found Bob Briski's answer helpful, but I believe Savon has been updated since his answer. Here's a small example based on the latest documentation:

```
require 'savon'

client = Savon.client(
  wsdl: 'https://webservice.s6.exacttarget.com/etframework.wsdl',
  wsse_auth: [username, password],
  log: false,
  convert_request_keys_to: :camelcase
)

response = client.call(:retrieve, message: {
  retrieve_request: {
    object_type: 'List',
    properties: ['ID', 'List.ListName', 'List.Type', 'List.Category', 'Client.ID']
  }
})
```